# Angularjs - add additional row inside a tr ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Ng-repeat is present on a table row

My query is how can we achieve the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in y">
     Looping here....
 </tr>
```

Now as data object is looping on a `<tr>`. I have a scenario where I have to display data of 1 row in two `<tr>`.

Eg.

Table

- Data1     data1.2     data1.3     data1.4
- Data2     data2.2
- Data2b   data2.3     data2.4
- Data3     data3.2     data3.3     data3.4
- Data4    data4.2      data4.3

I.e. display data of 1 row in two

Can't use ng-repeat-end

Comment: Why can you not use `ng-repeat-end`?

Comment: Ng-repeat-end is already used. Need to display 2 tr inside it.

Comment: I don't think it's an issue of using another `ng-repeat-end`. In any case, show more of your code and where the other `ng-repeat-start`/`ng-repeat-end` are used - if this is indeed a problem

Answer (score 21):

1) You can combine `ng-if` with `ng-repeat` and 2) `ng-repeat` supports multi-element with `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]">
  <td>{{item}}</td><td>something else</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-if="item % 2 === 0" ng-repeat-end>
  <td colspan="2">-even</td>
</tr>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/l1SHaRpgk52cq28JTwzG?p=preview)**

Comment: in my case, i had to include additional <td> in ng-repeat this worked gr8 !

Answer (score 2):

I modified the solution [New Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968155/new-dev) provided for my purposes & thought I'd share since it really saved me.

I needed a solution to repeat my table header row after every *n*th row as an alternative to a "frozen/fixed upon scrolling" header row, which just isn't feasible for my use case.

In this example, I'm showing the header row after every 25 rows, but not if it's going to be the last row in the table: (($index+1) != itemCollection.length).

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column Header 1 - Value</th>
      <th>Column Header 2 - Index</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in itemCollection">
      <td>{{item}}</td>
      <td>{{$index}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end="" ng-if="(($index+1) % 25 === 0) && ($index+1) != itemCollection.length">
      <th>Column Header 1 - Value</th>
      <th>Column Header 2 - Index</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Check out the modified [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jP58u17FxRif95XfBTqr?p=preview).  For simplicity's sake, I used an inline collection, so the "not if it's going to be the last row in the table" logic isn't included (as you'll see with the unneeded column header at the very bottom), but you get the picture.

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat tbody instead of tr.

```
<tbody ng-repeat="x in y" >
  <tr>
    <td>{{X. row data}}</td>
    <td>{{X. row data 2}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      {{X. secondRowData}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Already ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end are used. The data that has to be displayed in 2 <tr> is present in ng-repeat-end. Now i want to display data in 2 <tr> inside ng-repeat-end for a single iteration.

Comment: Works, but probably not the best solution - I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30424660/5127934) is the proper way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat-start=x in y>
  <td>selectbox here
<tr\>

<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if=somecondition>
  <td>label data <\td>
<\tr>
```

So now we have already used ng-repeat-end. Inside ng-repeat-end i have to display 2 rows for a single iteration.

```
<tr><td indexis1>selectbox<\td><\tr>
 <tr><td indexis2>label primary<\td><\tr>
<tr><td indexis2>label secondary<\td><\tr>
```

This is a rough code snippet and there are numerous td already present in code.