# How do I create a new row inside an angular ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table

I have an `ng-repeat` creating rows, and I want to insert a new row periodically, but the logic for creating this is inside the row and ends up messing up the nesting, for example:

```
  <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>

       <!-- this doesn't work well -->
       <tr ng-if='items[$index].day != items[$index-1].day'>
       <td colspan=2>
       NEW DAY
       </td>
       </tr>

       <td>{{item.name}}</td>
       <td>{{item.day}}</td>

    </tr>
```

I want the "day divider" rows amongst the data rows whenever the day changes.

Comment: Could you explain more what exactly you wanted to do?

Comment: maybe adding an empty `td` for the ~else~ condition, for example: `<td ng-if='items[$index].day == items[$index-1].day' colspan=22></td>`

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar Made a typo in the code, have edited should make more sense also said that I want the "NEW DAY" rows amongst the data rows whenever item.day changes.

Comment: @nickponline you can not nest `tr` in another `tr`. That is not valid html

Comment: Take a look at first answer with working demo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424507/angularjs-add-additional-row-inside-a-tr-ng-repeat

Comment: @RomanKoliada but that would create divider after the changed row, I need it to be before.

Comment: I've modified a bit Demo from @ivin raj for your purposes: https://jsfiddle.net/koljada/4oe6a30g/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end as follow:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
       <td>{{item.name}}</td>
       <td>{{item.day}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
       <td>Expand/collapse content</td>
    </tr>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/4oe6a30g/)

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that, much less complicated and more more friendly than my solution. +1. OP you will want to use `ng-show`/`ng-hide` alongside `ng-repeat-end`.

Comment: This doesn't place an Expand/collapse context as the first row.

Comment: <tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
       <td>{{item.name}}</td>
       <td>{{item.day}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
       <td>collapse </td>
    </tr>

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

What about having new method in your controller like `isDivider(item)` which would return bool value.

I did not test this but it should work:

```
    <tr ng-repeat='item in items'>

       <td ng-if="isDivider(item)==true" colspan=2>NEW DAY<td>

       <td ng-if="isDivider(item)==false">{{item.name}}</td>
       <td ng-if="isDivider(item)==false">{{item.day}}</td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: This will create all the data and then all the day divider rows. I want the day divider rows amongst the data when the day changes.

Answer (score 0):

This works although it seems gross:

```
         <tr ng-repeat-start='item in items'>

               <tr ng-if='items[$index].day != items[$index-1].day'>
               <td colspan=2>
               NEW DAY
               </td>
               </tr>



               <td>{{item.name}}</td>
               <td>{{item.day}}</td>

            </tr>

      <!-- dummy row -->
      <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might want to group the data by days and do two nested repeaters.

```js
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rows = [
    { name: 'one', day: 'monday' },
    { name: 'two', day: 'monday' },
    { name: 'three', day: 'tuesday' },
    { name: 'four', day: 'tuesday' },
    { name: 'five', day: 'thursday' }
  ];
  
  var groupBy = function(arr, property) { // you can use Underscore instead
    var output = {};
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var item = arr[i];
      if (typeof output[item[property]] === 'undefined') {
        output[item[property]] = [];
      }
      if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        output[item[property]].push(item);
      }
    }
    
    return output;
  };
  
  $scope.groupedRows = groupBy($scope.rows, 'day');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <table>
      <!-- it's valid to have more than one tbody -->
      <tbody ng-repeat="(key, group) in groupedRows">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in group">
          <td>{{row.name}}</td>
          <td>{{row.day}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** if you want the grouped rows to be ordered properly, you might want to store your day as an integer, and only change how it displays. Since you can't "actually" sort object keys, they auto-sort alphabetically in the JS engine, you can have them sorted properly if they are numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Plz try this one

```
   <body ng-app="ngAnimate">
  Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" aria-label="Toggle ngHide"><br/>
<div>
  Show:
  <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="checked">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> I show up when your checkbox is checked.
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  Hide:
  <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-hide="checked">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> I hide when your checkbox is checked.
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/U0YybTyJK95ygR1r8nsb?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use repeat-start and repeat-end:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
       <td>{{item.name}}</td>
       <td>{{item.day}}</td>
    </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end> 
    <td colspan="2">
</tr>
```