# angular js ng-repeat issues inside html

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have like this now.

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in xx">
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>{{a.name}}</td>

</tr>
<tr ng-repeat ="b in kk">
   <td>Id</td>
   <td>{{b.ll}}</td>
</tr>
```

But i need the two loops inside one tr.Means, I need 4 td inside one tr.
How can I do it.

Comment: Do you want to put "Name", "a.name", "Id" & "b.ll" all in one table row ?

Comment: Please refer this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957674/how-do-i-create-a-new-row-inside-an-angular-ng-repeat/31958129#31958129

Comment: yes. BUt the number of entries in both array may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to reply on the $index to reference the second array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="a in xx">
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>{{a.name}}</td>
  <td>Id</td>
  <td>{{kk[$index].ll}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: yes. i got, but if number of entries is more in second loop then this wont work correctly. I will miss some data.

Comment: can you provide the exact example with data? It should work you will have to manipulate the index value accordingly and moreover the array kk (or inner looping array) should have pre-defined known values like atleast the count should be known in advance. You can then add [$index]+1....+2...etc accordingly.