# How to add a td with colspan in angularjs for each iteration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to do this in angular:

```
<tr (each)>
  <td>{{attribute1}}</td>
  <td>{{attribute2}}</td>
  <td>{{attribute3}}</td>
</tr>
```

But I need a wide TD after each TR with colspan 3 like:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="3">Another content for row 1</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the (angular each) is inside the `<tr>`, for my understanding, there's no way to put the colspan row...

Can you help?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30424507/angularjs-add-additional-row-inside-a-tr-ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like this for **Angular 1**:

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in items">
  <td>{{item.attribute1}}</td>
  <td>{{item.attribute2}}</td>
  <td>{{item.attribute3}}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
   <td colspan="3">Another content for row 1</td>
</tr>
```

here are the docs

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Otherwise you need to do something like this for **Angular 2**

```
<template *ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items">
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.attribute1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.attribute2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.attribute3}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">Another content for row 1</td>
    </tr>
</template>
```